# Cloning a a simple boxed type with C#

Tags: c#, clone

I have read a bunch of code about C# object cloning.

For some reasons I wanted to use reflection to perform the cloning.

I have an object that contains a simple data (`int`, `string`, `List<string>`, `List<int>`, `DateTime`, `double` or other simple value types). The object is created by simple boxing.

```
object ob = 5;
```

Now using code like [this DeepCloneHelper](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSDeepCloneObject-8a53311e/sourcecode?fileId=71804&pathId=542308700) or [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1111658/Fast-Deep-Copy-by-Expression-Trees-C-Sharp) fail all in the same way. Using this clone code on an object containing a primitive data they return the same object. The following sample code will return ob2 that is ReferenceEqual to ob1

```
object ob1 = 5;  
object ob2 = DoSomeClone(ob1);
```

How to write a simple clone code for such types?

I searched a lot also here in SO, so I appologize if this question is a duplicate.

Explanation:
I have a common object that holds some data and references (origin of the data). The plain data itself (datatype see above) is saved in an object. For the primitive types it is just the boxed value.

In some cases I need a copy of the outer class, because I want to give this function to a simulation that might change the data. The object itself is cloned via a constructor. Now I need a copy of the data too. Using any cloning function would create a copy not a clone of the values.

Comment: Can you tell us why you need to do this? You can't change the primitive type that is boxed because it is immutable.

Comment: And just to be clear, you can't have a boxed list, unless you're talking a different type of list than `List<T>`. `List<T>` is not a value type.

Comment: Using Reflection to clone objects is just going to be messy and error-prone. Is there some particular reason the standard ways of cloning, or even deep-cloning with serialize/deserialize aren't good enough?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `List` and `string` are definitely not simple types, nor do they get boxed - they are reference types so they don't need boxing. *Value types* on the other hand are copied when passed around.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos they are copied unless they are boxed.  And OP wants a solution to force them to be copied even if they are boxed.

Comment: @Kirill which doesn't really matter for the primitives, as they are immutable. It would make sense if the OP meant *writable structs*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: While the primitives themselves are immutable, it's possible in some languages (not C#, other than via reflection) to change "which value is in the box". So while it's an unusual request, it's reasonable for some scenarios.

Comment: Changed my question and found the answer to your comments! If this question is not valuable, please write a comment or downvote it. I will delete it...

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given in the comments: **Primitive types are immutable when boxed and so there is no need for cloning!**

So storing a new value (i.e. int) in it will create a new object!

Comment: and so there is no need for cloning.

Comment: Thanks, I will add this

Comment: You can even take out the "when boxed". Given `int i = 1; i = 2;`, a new `int` instance is overwriting the original `int`, so that the original `int` is never modified, but ceases to be. This is a bit philosophical for `int`, since there is no difference between that and modifying the original `int`, but it becomes apparent with e.g. `struct S { public readonly int i; };` and variables `S s1, s2;`, `s1 = s2;` is perfectly valid. If that assignment were a modification of the original `S` instance, the compiler would have to flag it for assigning to a readonly field.